# Mnesia Errors case_clause in QLC query without a case clause

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have the following function for a hacky project:

```
% The Record variable is some known record with an associated table.
Query = qlc:q([Existing ||
  Existing <- mnesia:table(Table),
  ExistingFields = record_to_fields(Existing),
  RecordFields = record_to_fields(Record),
  ExistingFields == RecordFields
]).
```

The function `record_to_fields/1` simply drops the record name and ID from the tuple so that I can compare the fields themselves. If anyone wants context, it's because I pre-generate a unique ID for a record before attempting to insert it into Mnesia, and I want to make sure that a record with identical fields (but different ID) does not exist.

This results in the following (redacted for clarity) stack trace:

```
{aborted, {{case_clause, {stuff}},
      [{db, '-my_func/2-fun-1-',8, ...
```

Which points to the line where I declare `Query`, however there is no case clause in sight. What is causing this error?

(Will answer myself, but I appreciate a comment that could explain how I could achieve what I want)

EDIT: this wouldn't be necessary if I could simply mark certain fields as unique, and Mnesia had a dedicated `insert/1` or `create/1` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, I think your solution is clearer anyway (although it seems you can pull the `record_to_fields(Record)` portion outside the comprehension so it isn't getting calculated over and over.)

Yes, list comprehensions can only have generators and assignments. But you can cheat a little by writing an assignment as a one-element generator. For instance, you can re-write your expression as this:

```erlang
RecordFields = record_to_fields(Record),
Query = qlc:q([Existing ||
  Existing <- mnesia:table(Table),
  ExistingFields <- [record_to_fields(Existing)],
  ExistingFields == RecordFields
]).
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the QLC DSL does not allow assignments, only generators and filters; as per the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Syntactically QLCs have the same parts as ordinary list
>   comprehensions:
>
> `[Expression || Qualifier1, Qualifier2, ...]`
>
> Expression (the template)
>   is any Erlang expression. **Qualifiers are either filters or generators.**
>   **Filters are Erlang expressions returning `boolean()`**. Generators have
>   the form `Pattern <- ListExpression`, where `ListExpression` is an
>   expression evaluating to a query handle or a list.

Which means we cannot variable assignments within a QLC query.

Thus my only option, insofar as I know, is to simply write out the query as:

```
Query = qlc:q([Existing ||
  Existing <- mnesia:table(Table),
  record_to_fields(Existing) == record_to_fields(Record)
]).
```